# Jquery Ajax response delay in between callback function response

Tags: jquery

I want to delay 5 seconds in between response of ajax callback.

```
     checkSucess = function() {

    // Jquery Ajax with url,params and response
      doPost('sucess.php',
        'first=' + first,
       function(response) {

        var status = checkSucess(response,'X');

                 // I want to  delay 5 seconds with this code before next  checkSucess() function is called. 

                $('#SlideShow').html('<img id="SlideShows" src="images/loadingAnimation.gif">').delay(5000);

                $('#button'+response).val("O");
                $('#SlideShow').empty();
                // End block.

        var status = checkSucess(response,'O');



       });

   return response;
```

Delay is not working according to needed.Image is not showing.How can solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Use setTimeout:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Comment: If setTimeOut is used I want to create a new function and pass response to it . But It will give an error 'response is not defined'.How I will solve this?

Comment: I think you're confused because you don't get to sit in JavaScript for  5 seconds synchronously, blocking the web page from running.  You need to define a function that you can run by itself.  Then schedule when it will run and let it be called when the scheduler says it's time.